# Finding an indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I want to find

$$\int \frac{x^4}{\sqrt{x^{10}-2}}dx $$
I tried to use $x=2\tan(t)$ and tried $((\sqrt{x^{10}-2})'*\frac{1}{x^4})*\frac 15$ and partial integration but got stucked.

Thanks

Comment: I edited your question. Is that what you want to ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not calculate the whole integral, but there is my attempt:

Let $u=x^5, du=5x^4 dx$. $$\int \frac{x^4}{\sqrt{x^{10}-2}}dx=\frac15 \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2 - 2}}$$

i think you can then solve the above by trigo substitution. Once you finish the calculation, we substitute back $u=x^5$.

Comment: Same time, same answer !! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici : Nice!:)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Since $x^4$ looks like the derivative of $x^5$ and that $x^{10}=(x^5)^2$, why not to try $x^5=u$; this will give you $5x^4~dx=du$ and then $$I=\int \frac{x^4}{\sqrt{x^{10}-2}}dx=\frac 15 \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2-2}}$$ where appears now an antiderivative which probably is very familiar to you.

I am sure that you can take from here.